# Javascript Font-Resizer Overflowing Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, fonts, font-size

I've been working on a website (scibowltest.github.io) in which the font-size for an element is determined by javascript. If you go in to the website, it looks fine when displayed on a laptop/desktop with the browser at full width and height. However, if you resize the window to make the width smaller, the font starts to overflow the div in which it is supposed to be contained.

The following code is for the function font-sizer, which determines how big the font-size will be.

```
function fontSizer(text, box, scale) {
  var textID = "#" + text;
  var boxID = "#" + box;
  var boxHeight = $(boxID).height();
  var boxWidth = $(boxID).width();
  var fontSize = 0;
  if (boxHeight >= boxWidth) {
    fontSize = (boxWidth * scale) + "px";
  } else if (boxHeight < boxWidth) {
    fontSize = (boxHeight * scale) + "px";
  } else {}

  var textHeight = $(textID).height();
  var textWidth = $(textID).width();

  if (textWidth > boxWidth) {
    fontSize = ((fontSize * (scale * boxWidth)) / (textWidth)) + "px";
  } else {}

  $(textID).css("font-size", fontSize);
}
```

The function works based on the smaller dimension of the div (box) containing the text. However, the last if statement tries to compensate for those situations in which the text's width is greater than the div's width to try to shrink the fontsize so that the text's width is equal to the div's width times the scale.

Obviously, from looking at the website, this last if statement isn't working. If anyone could help, I would appreciate it!

Comment: I would suggest using the new font measures (`vw`,'vh',`vmin`,`vmax`) - some of these should fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure CSS solution you can use some of the new [length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh) that are intended exactly for your usecase - different screen sizes.

Play around with `vw`,`vh`,`vmin`,`vmax` and see what gives you the best results. I personally use `vmin` a lot.

It requires a bit of fiddling but would eliminate the use of javascript.

Also I used [`<wbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) in this example (although it should not be needed) - a "word break opportunity" to additionally prevent overflowing.

```css
div {
  width: 40vmin;
  font-size: 8vmin;
  border: 1px solid red;
  resize: both;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  width: 40vw;
  font-size: 8vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
  resize: both;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
resize the screen to see the fonts scale:

<div>Start/<wbr>Stop</div>

<p>Start/<wbr>Stop</p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for replying - I looked at another stackoverflow question and found this solution, but when implementing it into my CSS, I wasn't able to work it. I'll try again, but I remember that the problem was when I set the font-size at the div level, the font-size would appear differently than if I set it at the h1 level. Does anyone have a reasoning for this.

Comment: Also, I think that this solution would run into the same problem again - I could set the font-size based on vmin, but if the width is only slightly larger than the height, then the font-size would be calculated on the height, and the text would continue to overflow the div boundary.

Comment: I have used this a lot and am pretty sure it can be done without overflowing. Have you tried the code example in full screen mode?

Comment: Yours doesn't overflow because both your height and width of the div that you are containing changes. The problem with my js is when only the width of the browser window change - then the height is still smaller than the width, but only barely. The font-size through vmin would still be calculated off the height, but since the font is more than one character the other characters would overflow.

Comment: However, I'll look into the vmin solution, check if it works, and get back to the thread.